# Rough outline on how to make a java web app that interfaces with a SQL database?

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm learning java (coming from c#, c++ and python) and am starting a project in which I want to make a web app that interfaces with a SQL database and then displays the results on a webpage.

Now, I know I could do this very easily with ASP.Net but I want to do it in java, just wondering what sort of frameworks I will need to use (if any)?

I've been trying to look up this on google but I couldn't really find anything solid.

Answer (score 1):

The direct equivalent for ASP.Net in Java is JSP or Java Server Pages. Here's a great tutorial to start with: http://www.jsptut.com/

You don't need any special frameworks but you'll need a server like you need IIS for ASP.Net. I'd recommend Apache Tomcat as the server base.

You can also use IDEs like Netbeans or Eclipse which take care of the hard work of placing your JSP files in appropriate directories in the server but I recommend doing it the manual way which will help you learn the working of the internals better. Compared to ASP.Net, JSP on Tomcat can get a bit messy to set up but it is easy once you understand. This tutorial here https://blog.udemy.com/apache-tomcat-tutorial/ explains the process in a simple way.